# Selenium - Find a child element under a DIV

Tags: html, class, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parent-child

Can someone help me with the below HTML:

```
<div id="ext-156" class="menuBar">
  <a id="ext-234" href="javascript:void(0);" class="active">
    <i id="ext-365" class="menuItem"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

I am looking for the element with class "menuItem" and only from inside the div with class "menuBar" in Selenium.

Answer (score 7):

Well, depending on what language you're using, the method call will be different, but the selector should be the same across language bindings:

css:

```
"div.menuBar .menuItem"
```

xpath:

```
"//div[@class='menuBar']//*[@class='menuItem']"
```

In java, the call would look like this:

```
driver.find(By.cssSelector("div.menuBar .menuItem"));
```

Comment: I guess you meant to write `//div[@class='menuBar']//i[@class='menuItem']` as xpath?

Comment: @Saifur you can do the xpath selector without the tag name.  It might require a wildcard (*) though....been a while since I've used xpath.

Comment: In that case you need to use * for tag independent search as shown by @SiKing

Comment: @aholt if the element comes under more than 1 div then how will you make the nested cssSelector expression?

Comment: not sure what your meaning is.  maybe update your question with an example of what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath: `//div[@class='menuBar']//*[@class='menuItem']`.